# How to write a classification algorithm in tensorflow using keras in python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, classification

I have a training set of 2 images which has 64 features and a label attached to them i.e. matched/not matched.

How can I feed this data in a neural network using keras?

My data is as follows:

```
[
    [
        [
            239, 
            1, 
            255, 
            255, 
            255, 
            255, 
            2, 
            0, 
            130, 
            3, 
            1, 
            101, 
            22, 
            154, 
            0, 
            240, 
            30, 
            0, 
            2, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            128, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            71, 
            150, 
            212
        ], 
        [
            239, 
            1, 
            255, 
            255, 
            255, 
            255, 
            2, 
            0, 
            130, 
            3, 
            1, 
            101, 
            22, 
            154, 
            0, 
            240, 
            30, 
            0, 
            2, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            128, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            71, 
            150, 
            212
        ], 
        "true"
    ], 
    [
        [
            239, 
            1, 
            255, 
            255, 
            255, 
            255, 
            2, 
            0, 
            130, 
            3, 
            1, 
            81, 
            28, 
            138, 
            0, 
            241, 
            254, 
            128, 
            6, 
            0, 
            2, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            128, 
            0, 
            128, 
            2, 
            128, 
            2, 
            192, 
            6, 
            224, 
            6, 
            224, 
            62, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            13, 
            62
        ], 
        [
            239, 
            1, 
            255, 
            255, 
            255, 
            255, 
            2, 
            0, 
            130, 
            3, 
            1, 
            81, 
            28, 
            138, 
            0, 
            241, 
            254, 
            128, 
            6, 
            0, 
            2, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            128, 
            0, 
            128, 
            2, 
            128, 
            2, 
            192, 
            6, 
            224, 
            6, 
            224, 
            62, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            0, 
            13, 
            62
        ], 
        "true"
    ], 
    ....
]
```

I want to train neural network so that after training if I provide it 2 array of 64 features then it should able to tell whether they matched or not?

Comment: You should check a tutorial about creating a classifier with 2 outputs. There are plenty online.

Comment: checked, but they didn't solve my problem. Can you suggest any specific tutorial for this?

Comment: Basically you did not provide any concrete problem to be solved. These kind of questions are not well received in general . You should be provide a [minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you kind of extracted the futures already, I'd suggest by just going with some dense layers and convert the "true" and "false" to a 1 and 0 respectively, and just use a sigmoid on the final dense layer.

Try to experiment with something simple first, see how it goes and continue from there on, need more help, just ask

EDIT

```
def generator(batch_size=10, nr_features=126):
    feed_data = np.zeros((batch_size, nr_features))
    labels = np.zeros(batch_size)
    i = 0
    for entry in data:
        if entry.pop(-1) == "true":
            labels[i] = 1
        else:
            labels[i] = 0
        feed_data[i, :] = np.array(entry).flatten()
        i += 1
        if not (i % batch_size):
            i = 0
            yield feed_data, labels


model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(126, input_dim=126))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(20))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1))
model.add(keras.layers.Activation('sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
for d, l in generator():
    model.train_on_batch(d, l)
```

So what happens,

the data in the generator is your full data, I pop out the true/false, convert it to 1/0 and put it into the label array, I concat all features as a feature vecotr of 126. So feed_data.shape = (10, 126) and labels.shape = (10).

I feed that to a simple fully connected network, one that ends up with a sigmoid. Sigmoid is useful for probablilty, so in this case the output will be the probability that a feature vecotr is true. and I just feed the data.

Simple example, is not the full code but should get you started, I tested it, and it runs for me, I did not train anything yet though, that's something for you, good luck!

Oh, and questions, ask away

Comment: yes one thing I want to ask, I have 2 images to match, each has 64 features. So, will my input layer have 64+64=128 nodes?

Comment: Not really, the input will have 64 nodes, and you'll feed it a batch of 2, but wait, you only have 2 images? Then don't use deep learning, just openCV, you cannot train anything with only 2 images, or am I confused xd

Comment: I have data in this format, [  
   [  
      [  
         image 1
      ],
      [  
         image 2
      ],
      "true"
   ],
   [  
      [  
         image 1
      ],
      [  
         image 2
      ],
      "true"
   ],
   [  
      [  
         image 1
      ],
      [  
         image 2
      ],
      "true"
   ],
   [  
      [  
         image 1
      ],
      [  
         image 2
      ],
      "true"
   ],
   ....
]

Comment: It would make sense to split the data up to be honest

Comment: I have 50 training examples as of now, I am planning to run multiple iterations on it

Comment: Well the labels need to be out of there anyway, and you could contagonate the images, I'll help with some code to feed it once I get home to my laptop, mobile is not very handy for this

Comment: Thanks a lot, Understood the concept. Its working now. Accuracy is 63.33%. I guess I need more data.